# Text to Speech Library Android?

Tags: android

i'm going to develop application in which is need implement text to speech.

Please give me any strong library link, which works too good for me!!! except Flite to engine library.

Which is library is best to do this???

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: did you [search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+TTS&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=raG_U8CXI-rV8gf_hoHoAQ#channel=fflb&q=android+tts+example&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official)?

Comment: yes i search on this android is providing this, but i need to suuport maximum languages. i know abour iSearch, eSpeak, AT&T, But i need more strong library to support maximum number of languages.

Comment: yes , i search a lot and finding number of libraries, but i need a library which supports maximum number of languages!!! i know about iSpeak, AT&T

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this you do not need to use any library.You can use android`s own text to speech engine.Use the following code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tts_main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        // button on click event
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

            // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Create a xml file with a button and an edittext.The tts engine will speak out the input that you will give in the edittext on clicking of the button.

Comment: I have already used this, but i need to support maximum number of langueages!!!

Comment: Thanks, where is the documentation for this? I could not find it.