# How can I add text-to-speech in tensorflow lite object detection android based application?

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection, vision

I am trying to build an app that will help visually impaired individuals detect objects/hurdles in their way. So using the TensorFlow library and the android text-to-speech once an object is detected, the application will let the user know what the object is. I'm currently trying to build off the Android Object Detection Example provided by TensorFlow, however I'm struggling to find where the strings of the labels of the bounding boxes are stored so that I can call this when running the text-to-speech

Answer (score 1):

I saw the project of Object detection. You can find the results of the inference in 2 places inside project:

First you can find them inside

```
TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java
```

There you can add a log statement at line [227](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java) for

> recognitions object

for example

```
Log.i("Recognitions", String.valueOf(recognitions.get(0).getTitle()));
```

Second inside

```
DetectorActivity.java
```

You can log

> results object

at line [181](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/DetectorActivity.java).

Then you can follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24693542/7118084) to integrate TtS. I am a little pesimist of the result because MultiboxTracker gives a lot of results in every second....and I don't know the performance if a lot of objects are detected!!

You have to filter some results.

I am really interested on the result!!

If you need more help tag me

Happy coding!

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your help. I just tried that part with the logging and you're right about the number of results every second, so I'm trying to find a way maybe to delay the time between each detection

Comment: How about upvoting then? :) :)

Comment: I did, but unfortunately, as I have less than 15 reputations it doesn't publicly change the score sadly.

Comment: No problem.. Happy coding then.. Tag me again if you have problems

Comment: Hey quick question, just getting back to this as I had exams, so I added the delay factor first, but then I figured the best way to sort of implement the Tts would be with a button, so I made a full screen button and made it transparent so the user would be able to click anywhere on screen when they want to receive verbal feedback. The problem I'm having now is importing the string that we logged in detector activity telling us the object to the activity that will perform the Tts once the button is clicked, any idea how to work around this? not sure how to extract the string from that object?