# How do I make it so the the prompt, speaks to the user?

Tags: android, android-studio, speech-recognition

I am building an app that needs speech recognition as a requirement in Android Studio, I am wanting more interaction between the user and the App. At current, the App is able to take the user to another activity through telling the App where the user wants to go, but i was hoping for more communication so there is speech from the App which asks the user ' how can i assist you' rather than it written in text.

Is this possible? I am very novice to this - so a good explanation will be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Activity - 'homescreen'

```
public class homescreen extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
private TextView mVoiceInputTv;
private ImageView imgSpeech;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen);
    mVoiceInputTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mtext);
    imgSpeech = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSpeech);
    imgSpeech.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startVoiceInput();
        }
    });
}

private void startVoiceInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hello, how can i assist you?");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            if(mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("activity")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),quizactivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if(mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().equals("logout")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Conversation type interaction like Alexa or Google Actions is usually done via servers. You can play a audio file/use TTS to speak text, but I'm not aware of a function/library to hand off to a cloud based voice assistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted a demo of the `TextToSpeech` library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693420/text-to-speech-library-android) - the voices (and how good they sound) depend on the user's device and what they have installed.

Once you have an instance initialised you can just use the `speak` method to tell it what to say, seems fairly painless! It'll probably get a little trickier when you have multiple things you want it to say, you need to make it interrupt itself or say a thing as the next line, that kind of logic. But the actual speaking is fairly straightforward!